# CSS not working properly for ASP.Net Button

Tags: css, asp.net

I am using ASP.NET web form in Visual studio 2013.

I am using the following CSS code snippet for button,

```
  .button::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      background: #071017;
      border: 50vh solid #1d4567;
      width: 30vh;
      height: 30vh;
      border-radius: 50%;
      display: block;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      z-index: 0;
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
              transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
    }
```

and

```
.button:active::before, .button:focus::before {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.28s ease 0.364s, -webkit-transform 1.12s ease;
  transition: opacity 0.28s ease 0.364s, -webkit-transform 1.12s ease;
  transition: transform 1.12s ease, opacity 0.28s ease 0.364s;
  transition: transform 1.12s ease, opacity 0.28s ease 0.364s, -webkit-transform 1.12s ease;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Its working fine for html button, but not properly working for ASP.NET button.

```
<div class="button-container">
            <asp:Button ID="submit" class="button" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="submit_Click" />
            <button type="submit" class="button"><span>Submit</span></button>
        </div>
```

Here is my ASP.NET web form

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="OrderTakingUI.aspx.cs" Inherits="ResponsiveWebApplication.OrderTakingUI" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Orders</title>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<style>
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
body,
input,
select,
textarea,
body * {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body::after, body::before,
input::after,
input::before,
select::after,
select::before,
textarea::after,
textarea::before,
body *::after,
body *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f2f2f2, #e6e6e6);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #f2f2f2, #e6e6e6);
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0 2em;
}

.container {
  max-width: 40rem;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  padding: 3rem 5rem 0;
  border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
  -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.28s ease, -webkit-transform 0.28s ease;
  transition: box-shadow 0.28s ease, -webkit-transform 0.28s ease;
  transition: box-shadow 0.28s ease, transform 0.28s ease;
  transition: box-shadow 0.28s ease, transform 0.28s ease, -webkit-transform 0.28s ease;
}

fieldset {
  margin: 0 0 3rem;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
}


/*------------------------------input type text and textarea and other starts-----*/
.form-inline > .form-group,
.form-inline > .btn {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.form-help {
  margin-top: 0.125rem;
  margin-left: 0.125rem;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

.form-group input {
  height: 1.9rem;
}
.form-group textarea {
  resize: none;
}
.form-group select {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1rem;
  height: 1.6rem;
  padding: 0.125rem 0.125rem 0.0625rem;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  line-height: 1.6;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.form-group .input-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.25rem;
  pointer-events: none;
  padding-left: 0.125rem;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #b3b3b3;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: normal;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.28s ease;
  transition: all 0.28s ease;
}
.form-group .bar {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 0.0625rem solid #999;
  display: block;
}
.form-group .bar::before {
  content: '';
  height: 0.125rem;
  width: 0;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -0.0625rem;
  position: absolute;
  background: #B73394;
  -webkit-transition: left 0.28s ease, width 0.28s ease;
  transition: left 0.28s ease, width 0.28s ease;
  z-index: 2;
}
.form-group input,
.form-group textarea {
  display: block;
  background: none;
  padding: 0.125rem 0.125rem 0.0625rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  border-width: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  line-height: 1.9;
  width: 100%;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.28s ease;
  transition: all 0.28s ease;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.form-group input[type="file"] {
  line-height: 1;
}
.form-group input[type="file"] ~ .bar {
  display: none;
}
.form-group select,
.form-group input:focus,
.form-group input:valid,
.form-group input.form-file,
.form-group input.has-value,
.form-group textarea:focus,
.form-group textarea:valid,
.form-group textarea.form-file,
.form-group textarea.has-value {
  color: #333;
}
.form-group select ~ .input-label,
.form-group input:focus ~ .input-label,
.form-group input:valid ~ .input-label,
.form-group input.form-file ~ .input-label,
.form-group input.has-value ~ .input-label,
.form-group textarea:focus ~ .input-label,
.form-group textarea:valid ~ .input-label,
.form-group textarea.form-file ~ .input-label,
.form-group textarea.has-value ~ .input-label {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: gray;
  top: -1rem;
  left: 0;
}
.form-group select:focus,
.form-group input:focus,
.form-group textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.form-group select:focus ~ .input-label,
.form-group input:focus ~ .input-label,
.form-group textarea:focus ~ .input-label {
  color: #B73394;
}
.form-group select:focus ~ .bar::before,
.form-group input:focus ~ .bar::before,
.form-group textarea:focus ~ .bar::before {
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.form-group {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 2.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 2.25rem;
}

/*------------------------------input type text and textarea and other ends-----*/


/*--------------------------------Button starts--------------------------------*/

.button-container {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  background: currentColor;
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: #B73394;
  margin: 3rem 0;
  padding: 0.75rem 3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.28s ease, color 0.28s ease, box-shadow 0.28s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.28s ease, color 0.28s ease, box-shadow 0.28s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
.button span {
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.button::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #071017;
  border: 50vh solid #1d4567;
  width: 30vh;
  height: 30vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
}
.button:hover {
  color: #B73394;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 18px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 3px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.button:active::before, .button:focus::before {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.28s ease 0.364s, -webkit-transform 1.12s ease;
  transition: opacity 0.28s ease 0.364s, -webkit-transform 1.12s ease;
  transition: transform 1.12s ease, opacity 0.28s ease 0.364s;
  transition: transform 1.12s ease, opacity 0.28s ease 0.364s, -webkit-transform 1.12s ease;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  opacity: 0;
}
.button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

/*--------------------------------Button ends--------------------------------

</style>
</head>


<body>

<div class="container">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" required=""></asp:DropDownList>
            <label for="select" class="input-label">Selectbox</label><i class="bar"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:TextBox ID="text" runat="server" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
            <label for="input" class="input-label">Textfield</label><i class="bar"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <asp:TextBox id="textarea" TextMode="multiline" Columns="50" Rows="5" runat="server" required="required" />
            <label for="textarea" class="input-label">Textarea</label><i class="bar"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="button-container">
            <asp:Button ID="submit" class="button" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="submit_Click" />
            <button type="submit" class="button"><span>Submit</span></button>
        </div>
    </form>  
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

I do not have much experience of using CSS with ASP.NET. I am expecting your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use css class in asp.net control use CssClass instead of class like below.

```
<asp:Button ID="submit" CssClass="button" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="submit_Click" />
```

Find out control's id after rendering in client side. Then implement CSS on that id. If you use id instead of css class.

Answer (score 2):

For `asp.button` you should use `CssClass` instead `class`:

```
<asp:Button ID="submit" CssClass="button" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="submit_Click" />
```

Comment: It's not working. Some part of CSS button class is working but not all. If you run my asp.net web form then you can notice that, while clicking on button there is a change between HTML and ASP.NET button. @arturas

Comment: It might be because of your <button>**<span>Submit</span>**</button>

Comment: Its working fine for HTML button, but not properly working for ASP.NET button. If you have time then please run the code. It will clarify all.  @arturas

Comment: Delete <span></span> from your <button>, and add <button value="Submit" />. Then it should look and work the same.

Comment: Please don't misunderstand my question. <button type="submit" class="button"><span>Submit</span></button> is working fine. CSS also working fine for this button. But not working properly for <asp:Button ID="submit" class="button" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="submit_Click" /> @arturas